# not receive negative numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/ntywf/1987/

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
    $('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this);
        $th.val($th.val().replace(/[-]/g, function(str) { 
            //alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease use only letters and numbers.'); 
            return ''; 
        }));
    });
});
```

what I want is to remove the "-" sign off when it is inserted. what happens is that the cursor is always the last decimal home. I just want this code not to let the user enter negative numbers. How can I do this? (the problem is to move the cursor within the input, since it is always sent to the last character)

Comment: Your code seems to work, in that it stops the user typing in a `-`, is there a specific issue you have with it? Note that you also want to perform this check on the `change` or `blur` events, as I can still copy the character in using the mouse.

Comment: could not understand the problem

Comment: the problem is to move the cursor within the input

Comment: From what I understand, you don't want to allow negative numbers. You are removing dashes from the input. You are performing validation on the fly. Perhaps you might want to look at your flow and validate on submission?

Comment: @tmutton yes, but my problem is that the cursor is always passed to the end, if you want to walk with the cursor left can not.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validate that a string is a positive integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)

Comment: There is no way the "-" key is blocked when inserted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a KeyCode ([Link](http://www.cambiaresearch.com/articles/15/javascript-char-codes-key-codes)) to verify what key you pressed, and use `replace` to remove it:

```js
$('input').keyup(function(e) {
        
    var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
    if(code == 109 || code == 189) { //Enter keycode
       //Do something
        var valor = $(this).val();
        $(this).val(valor.replace(/[-]/g, ''))
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `type = "numeric"` and `min="0"` This way you can prevent your **text-field** from accepting alphabets as well. **min=0** will always make sure that it will never accept -ve value.

```
<input type="number" min="0"/>
```

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npralhad/ntywf/1989/) will be helpful to you.

Comment: this does not solve my problem, since the customer to insert negative numbers manually.

Comment: I have tried it in the fiddle link and it is working. Its not allowing the `-` negative sign at all - even its not allowing the non-numeric values. What exact behavior you are looking at.  If you prepare a step-by-step **USE CASE** - that will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I have tried.

JS

```
$('input').keyup(function() {
        var $th = $(this).val();
        $th = $th.replace(/[-]/g, "");
        $(this).val($th)
        console.log( $(this).val());
    });
```

It will remove - sign from data.

Comment: it does not solve my problem if the input walk with the cursor to the left, he is always passed to the end. thanks

Comment: Its because keyup event goes in recursive fall

Comment: There is no way the "-" key is blocked when inserted?

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your problem

**What I have done is:**

- I have used the inbuilt HTML input field method `setSelectionRange()`, which *sets the start and end positions of the current text selection in an  element.* (From MDN)

*MDN Reference : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/setSelectionRange*

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {    
  $('input').keyup(function() {
    var $th = $(this);
    $th.val( $th.val().replace(/[-]/g, function(str) { 
        //alert('You typed " ' + str + ' ".\n\nPlease use only letters and numbers.'); 
        return ''; 
    } ) );
    $('input')[0].setSelectionRange(0, 0); //this method sets the range to zero text starting from 0 index to 0 index
  });
});
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/ntywf/1998/**

Comment: my question is that I want the mouse to continue in the position where it is. There is no way the "-" key is blocked when inserted? @dreamweiver

Comment: hmmm , the only way i think of blocking the `-` would be to check under `keypress` event than `keyup`

Comment: can you do a example plz?