# How to check if a string is a positive integer, allowing 0 and all-0 decimals

Tags: javascript, regex

So to check if a string is a positive integer, I have done some research and found this solution here by someone:
[Validate that a string is a positive integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)

```
function isNormalInteger(str) {
    return /^\+?(0|[1-9]\d*)$/.test(str);
}
```

However, I put this into test, and found that numbers with pure 0's on the decimal places does not seem to be working. For example:

> 15 ===> Works!
>
> 15.0 ====> Does not work :(
>
> 15.000 ===> Does not work :(

Build upon the existing method, how could I allow pure-0's on the decimal places and make them all work? Please note 15.38 should not work, but 15.00 should.

Comment: Integers don't have decimal places though, `15.0` isn't an integer, that's why it doesn't work when *"put to the test"*.

Comment: Yes preferably. I would like to not have leading "+" sign, and allow pure 0's in the decimal places. My best solution so far is  ^[0-9]\d*(\.0+)*$, does this seem to be correct? Thanks. @anubhava

Comment: Did you check my answer below? Isn't it already matching all of your conditions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all the function should be called `isNormalNumber` instead of `isNormalInteger` as it accepts decimals, then this is the REgex you need:

```js
    function isNormalNumber(str) {
      return /^\+*[0-9]\d*(\.0+)?$/.test(str);
    }

    alert(isNormalNumber("+10.0") + "::" + isNormalNumber("+10.9") + "::" + isNormalNumber("10"));
```

Returns `true::false:true`.

**EDIT:**

This is an edit to avoid matching leading zeros like in the numbers `001234` and `07878`:

```
^\+*[1-9]\d*(\.0+)?$|^0(\.0+)?$
```

Comment: Hi chsdk, the regex is great, but how could I allow 0 or 0.00 etc as well? I tried /^\+*[0-9]\d*(\.0+)*$/ is this correct? is [0-9] a valid range? @chsdk

Comment: Yep worked like a charm, and to eliminate the option of a leading "+", I just removed   \+*  correct?   @chsdk

Comment: It matches `0` which is not a positive integer and it also matches `0.0.0.0` which is not even a number.

Comment: Great catch! Thanks! Actually 0 is fine, for 0.0.0.0, I used ^[0-9]\d*(\.0+)?$ and now it seem to be working fine, I changed * to ? , is this a correct approach? @anubhava

Comment: Correct approach is using **without any regex** as I showed below but for regex `/^\d+(?:\.0+)?$/` is fine for you.

Comment: Actually, the solution that you suggested may rise an Exception and give `NaN` if the given str can't be parsed as Integer, for example `parseInt("Hello")` wil give `NaN`.

Comment: Not correct, there is no error. If you call `isNormalInteger("abc")` then **it will correctly return false**. Have you tested it?

Comment: Actually I found a situation this does not solve, that is, when I enter 001234, it will also accepts it. Anyway to remove the leading 0's ?  @chsdk

Comment: @photonacl take a look at my Edit.

Comment: @chsdk thanks, 0.0.0 still got accepted so I change the last * to ?, but after the change, 0.000 still not working where it supposed to be...

Comment: @chsdk, could you take a look if this is correct? ^(0|[1-9]\d*)(\.0+)?$  , i tested it couple of times and it seemed to be working nicely.

Comment: @photonacl This is what you need : `(\.0+)?` take a look at the one in my edit.

Answer (score 3):

No need to use regex here.

```
function isNormalInteger(str) {
   var n = parseInt(str);
   return n > 0 && n == +str;
}
```

Then test it:

```
isNormalInteger(15)
true
isNormalInteger(15.00)
true
isNormalInteger(15.38)
false
isNormalInteger(-15)
false
isNormalInteger(-15.1)
false
```

Comment: Actually this solution, may rise an Error because `parseInt()` will give `NaN` if the given string is not a valid number.

Comment: Nope, there is no error. If you call `isNormalInteger("abc")` it will **correctly return `false`**

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty

```
function isNormalInteger(str) {
    var ival=parseInt(str);
    return ival!=NaN && ival>=0 && ival==parseFloat(str);
}
```

Comment: ++ I prefer using this approach rather than using regex.