# Create mask for validate Only int numbers js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this view

I would like the field only accepts integer numbers when entering a value

**View**

```
<div class="RDANumber"></div>
  @Html.EditorFor(i => i.NumRDA)
<div class="clear"></div>
```

I try with js code bellow but no have a success.

Where am I going wrong?

What better way to do this?

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#RDANumber").keydown(function (event) {
        if (event.shiftKey) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
        }
        else {
            if (event.keyCode < 95) {
                if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
            else {
                if (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: `RDANumber` is a class on the div and you are referencing `#RDANumber` as an id.  Did you mean to have it as `$(".RDANumber")` or did you mean to reference the input by id `$("#NumRDA")`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate that a string is a positive integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write some javascript code because it's already built-in in ASP.Net MVC framework :

1. Check that you have client validation enabled and unobtrusive javaScript enabled in your web.config :

```xml
<appSettings>
  <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
  <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

2. Check that you reference correctly client side validation Javascript files in your Razor view : jQuery, jQuery Validate and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js.
3. Insert a validation attribute beside your `NumRDA` property in .cs file :

```cs
[Range(0, int.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Please enter valid integer Number")]
```

Answer (score 0):

you can choose other way

1-use a jquery plugin [click here](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/)

2-[only numeric (0-9) in HTML inputbox using jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

when you use

```
@Html.EditorFor(i => i.NumRDA)
```

it generates

```
<input type="text" name="NumRDA" />
```

for you

then you can use below code to prevent users to input non-digit characters

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$( "input[name='NumRDA']" ).keydown(function (event) {
    if (event.shiftKey) {
        event.preventDefault();
    }
    if (event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 8) {
    }
    else {
        if (event.keyCode < 95) {
            if (event.keyCode < 48 || event.keyCode > 57) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
        else {
            if (event.keyCode < 96 || event.keyCode > 105) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    }
});
});
```

[And here is the jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/t4s08fxx/)