# If statement that checks for negative numbers

Tags: javascript, function

I have a bank script. When the user deposits money I want to make sure it is a positive integer. If it isn't, I want to kick them out.

Here is my code:

```
<section id="pigBox">
      <img src="images/pig.png" />
      <label>Balance: </label><input type="text" id="balance" />
      <button id="deposit"> Deposit </button>
      <button id="withdraw"> Withdraw </button>
  </section><!-- end of pigBox-->

document.getElementById('balance').value = "1000"

var balance = document.getElementById('balance').value;
var deposit = document.getElementById('deposit');
var withdraw = document.getElementById('withdraw');

deposit.addEventListener('click', depositCash);
withdraw.addEventListener('click', withdrawCash);

function depositCash() {
  var depositAmt = prompt('How much would you like to deposit?');

  if(depositAmt != Number(depositAmt) && depositAmt) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');

  }
  balance = Number(balance) + Number(depositAmt);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
}

function withdrawCash() {
  var withdrawAmt = prompt('How much you you like to withdraw?');

  if(withdrawAmt != Number(withdrawAmt)) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');

  }
  balance = Number(balance) - Number(withdrawAmt);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
}
```

I tried using ..

```
else if(Number(depositAmt) < 0) {
 return alert('please enter a valid integer.');
}
```

But that doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks guys!

Comment: `But that doesn't work` What does it mean? do you get an error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Validate that a string is a positive integer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)

Comment: your code is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just check

```
if (depositAmt <= 0) {
    return alert('Please enter a positive integer.');
  }
```

Rewrite your `if` loop as `if` - `else if` - `else` to avoid checking all conditions.

```
 if (depositAmt != Number(depositAmt) && depositAmt) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');

  } else if (depositAmt <= 0) {
    return alert('Please enter a positive integer.');

  } else {
    balance = Number(balance) + Number(depositAmt);
    document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
  }
```

```js
document.getElementById('balance').value = "1000"
var balance, deposit, withdraw;
balance = document.getElementById('balance').value;
deposit = document.getElementById('deposit');
withdraw = document.getElementById('withdraw');

deposit.addEventListener('click', depositCash);
withdraw.addEventListener('click', withdrawCash);

function depositCash() {
  var depositAmt;
  depositAmt = prompt('How much would you like to deposit?');

  if (depositAmt != Number(depositAmt) && depositAmt) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');

  } else if (depositAmt <= 0) {
    return alert('Please enter a positive integer.');

  } else {
    balance = Number(balance) + Number(depositAmt);
    document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
  }
}

function withdrawCash() {
  var withdrawAmt;
  withdrawAmt = prompt('How much you you like to withdraw?');

  if (withdrawAmt != Number(withdrawAmt)) {
    return alert('Please enter a valid integer.');

  }
  balance = Number(balance) - Number(withdrawAmt);
  document.getElementById('balance').value = balance;
}
```

```html
<section id="pigBox">
  <img src="images/pig.png" />
  <label>Balance: </label><input type="text" id="balance" />
  <button id="deposit"> Deposit </button>
  <button id="withdraw"> Withdraw </button>
</section>
<!-- end of pigBox-->
```

Answer (score 1):

Check like this:

```
if(isNaN(Number(depositAmt)) || Number(depositAmt) < 0) {
    return alert('please enter a valid integer.');
}
```