# Validate multiple IP addresses separated by a comma without using regex

Tags: javascript

(Just want to note that I have checked other similar questions to mine but couldn't locate any that didn't use regex and the ones that didn't, didn't seem to work for my situation.)

Given a textarea field where a user can enter multiple IP addresses as a string separated by a comma, using JavaScript, what would be the best means to validate all these comma separated IP addresses, for example:

```
1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.,4.4.4.256
```

I obviously need to test for valid IP ranges as well as the three dots and four numbers.

I would prefer a solution that doesn't use regex.

Comment: What's wrong with regex, and also have you tried something so far? Like, splitting over `"."` and checking if each element is a number between 0 and 255?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split each ip and check if the numbers are valid. Also you can check if the dots (.) are 4.

```
function validateIp(ip) {
    if ( ip == null || ip === '' ) {
    return true;
  }

  const parts = ip.split('.');
  if(parts.length !== 4) {
    return true;
  }

  for(let i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
    const part = parseInt(parts[i]);
    if(part < 0 || part > 255) {
        return true;
    }
  }

  if(ip.endsWith('.')) {
    return true;
  }

  return false;
}

const input = '1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.,4.4.4.256';
const arr = input.split(',');
const wrongIps = arr.filter(validateIp);


console.log(arr)
console.log(wrongIps)
```

Of course, you can do the opposite thing and get only the valid IP addresses.

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/ht2175fx/)

Answer (score 0):

with `String.prototype.split` and `Array.prototype.every`

```js
const isValidIP = (ip) => {
  const ranges = ip && ip.trim().split('.');
  
  if(ranges && ranges.length === 4) {
    return ranges.every(range => range && !/\s/g.test(range) && (255 - range) >= 0);
  }
  
  return false;
}

const isValidIPs = (input) => input && input.split(',').every(isValidIP);


console.log(isValidIPs('1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.,4.4.4.256'));  // false
console.log(isValidIPs('1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,4.4.4.256'));         // false
console.log(isValidIPs('1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2'));                   // true
// with space between range
console.log(isValidIPs('1.1.1. 1, 2.2.2.2'));                 // false
// with space
console.log(isValidIPs(' 1.1.1.1 , 2.2.2.2 '));               // true
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way :

```js
var ip = "1.1.1.1,2.2.2,3.3.3.,4.4.4.256";
ip = ip.split(',');
ip.forEach(function(v,k){
 var ips = v.split('.');
 if(ips.length == 4){
  var flagip = 0;
  ips.forEach(function(v,k){
   if(isNaN(parseInt(v)) || parseInt(v) < 0 || parseInt(v) > 255){
    flagip = 1;
    }
  });
  if(flagip == 1){
   console.log('Invalid IP Address : ' + v);
  }else{
   console.log('Valid IP Address : ' + v);
  }
 }else{
  console.log('Invalid IP Address : ' + v);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `split`, `map`, and `reduce`.

1. Split into 2D array where first dimension is the result of `split(",")` and the second dimension is the result of `map` first dimension and `split(".")`
2. `reduce` each dimension where the first dimension is used to check the `length` of the second dimension. Then, check if each value in the second array is a valid positive integer (with help from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)) in the range of 0-255

This method returns `false` if there are spaces.

```js
function isNormalInteger(str) {
    var n = Math.floor(Number(str));
    return n !== Infinity && String(n) === str && n >= 0;
}

function validIPs(input) {
  return input.split(",").map(ip => ip.split(".")).reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (curr.length === 4) {
      return acc && curr.reduce((acc2, curr2) => {
        return acc2 && isNormalInteger(curr2) && parseInt(curr2) >= 0 && parseInt(curr2) < 256
      }, true)
    }
    return acc && false
  }, true)
}

let test1 = "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.,4.4.4.256"
let test2 = "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.256"
let test3 = "-1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.255"
let test4 = "1.1.1.1,2.2.2.2,3.3.3.3,4.4.4.255"
let test5 = "1.1.1.1,19.91.21.63"
let test6 = "1.1.1.1,19..91.21.63"
let test7 = "1.1.1.1,19.91. 21.63"

console.log(validIPs(test1))
console.log(validIPs(test2))
console.log(validIPs(test3))
console.log(validIPs(test4))
console.log(validIPs(test5))
console.log(validIPs(test6))
console.log(validIPs(test7))
```