# Date validation passes for some xss vectors

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, validation, jestjs

I am writing a test for a validator function which checks if a value passed is actually an instance of Date object or not. It returns either true or false. So if I pass a simple date, it passes as true that it is a safe value but now I am trying to test it by passing xss vectors (from this [list](https://github.com/payloadbox/xss-payload-list/blob/master/Intruder/xss-payload-list.txt)) but somehow some of them returns true, like this one:

```
<SVg </onlOad ="1> (_=prompt,_(1)) "">
```

or this:

```
<svg contentScriptType=text/vbs><script>MsgBox+1
```

Why is this happening and how can I fix it to return false for xss vectors?

This is the validator function:

```
const isTimeSafe = (value) => {
    const datetime = new Date(value);

    return (datetime instanceof Date && !isNaN(datetime.valueOf()));
}
```

Here's the test spec:

```
it('should return false when isTimeSafe is called with xss vectors', () => {

    const vectors = fs.readFileSync(`xssVectors.txt`).toString().split('\n');
    
    for (vector of vectors) {
       const isSafe = isTimeSafe(vector);

       expect(isSafe).toBe(false);
    }

});
```

Comment: There are only 3 string date formats supported by ECMA-262, anything else implementation dependent.So throwing random strings at `new Date(string)` is almost certain to produce unexpected results for some values and possibly different results in different implementations.

Comment: The only reliable way to validate that a string is a valid date is to parse it yourself (a library can heip) and test the values, which infers knowing the expected format.

Comment: @RobG Yeah this is what is happening here. I guess I have to change my validator. My time values are in Unix Epoch Time. So they should always be numbers. What's your suggestion about validating with only a regex that accepts only numbers?

Comment: [*Validate that a string is a positive integer*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10834796/validate-that-a-string-is-a-positive-integer)

Comment: May be post it as an answer so that I can close this thread.